# Как скруглить края у таблицы (border-radius)

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

```
    <table class="table_block">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Название</td>
                <td>Цена</td>
                <td>Цвета</td>
                <td>Продажи</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>50$</td>
                <td>Black, White</td>
                <td>104</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>70$</td>
                <td>Red, Blue, Grey</td>
                <td>255</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Нужно скруглить края у всей таблицы. Я уже как не пытался, к чему не применял... Я у первого td скгруглить пытался, у tr пытался. У всей таблице, понятно, не применяется. В общем все никак. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Засунуть в `div`, и его скруглить.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

А на самом деле для кросс-браузерности вот так:):

```
.table_block {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}​
```

Хотя наверно мой ответ уже неактуален.

Comment: почему же, он более полный и не менее правильный) я бы ТС порекомендовал бы именно его)

Comment: @hdimon, это уже будет не таблица.

Answer (score 10):

Насколько я помню, проблема глубже чем расстановка вендерных префиксов. `border-radius` конфликтует с `border-collapse: collapse`, которое, скорее всего используется. Я решал это двумя способами:

1. отказаться от `border-collapse: collapse`, а бордюры внутри таблицы рисовать ячейкам. Скажежм правый и нижний, а добивать first-child`ами.
2. не отказываться от `border-collapse: collapse`, но отказываться от вненего бордюра таблицы. Таблицу помещать в div. div`у рисовать бордюр и скруглять его.

P.S. Правда сейчас повторить не удается проблему :)

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так:

```
.table_block {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}​
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/5ALF5/)

Answer (score 3):

Если ты пробуешь сделать в Internet Explorer у тебя ничего не выйдет. В нем нужно использовать картинки - а в других браузерах должно работать как написано ниже.
Прямо в теге прописан стиль:

```
  <table style=' border-radius: 15px; border-style: solid;'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Название</td>
                    <td>Цена</td>
                    <td>Цвета</td>
                    <td>Продажи</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>50$</td>
                    <td>Black, White</td>
                    <td>104</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>70$</td>
                    <td>Red, Blue, Grey</td>
                    <td>255</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

И стиль прописан в классе:

```
<style type="text/css">
          .table_block{ border-radius: 15px; border-style: solid;}
</style>
  <table class ='table_block'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Название</td>
                <td>Цена</td>
                <td>Цвета</td>
                <td>Продажи</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>50$</td>
                <td>Black, White</td>
                <td>104</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>70$</td>
                <td>Red, Blue, Grey</td>
                <td>255</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно ещё проще:

```
table{ overflow: hidden; border-radius: 6px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.table_block {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}​`

Answer (score 2):

Тоже столкнулся с проблемой, у меня получилось следующим образом!...
Я сделал обертку `div` обертку вокруг `table`

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

table {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

border-radius: 20px;
overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 1):

Изменять свойство display не стоит. Зачем тогда использовать таблицу?
Моё решение такое:

```
tbody {
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

Пример: https://codepen.io/madebydima/pen/KKNmBxR

```css
.table_block td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.table_block tbody {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_block">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Название</td>
      <td>Цена</td>
      <td>Цвета</td>
      <td>Продажи</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>50$</td>
      <td>Black, White</td>
      <td>104</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>70$</td>
      <td>Red, Blue, Grey</td>
      <td>255</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Разве оно работает?

Comment: Для меня отлично сработало. Безусловно, это костыль. Но явно лучше, чем переопределять элементы таблицы в display: block (в чём смысл использования таблицы?).

Вот пример (добавил в свой ответ): https://codepen.io/madebydima/pen/KKNmBxR

Comment: Углы какие-то покусанные, но вообще да, внезапно. А display много зачем переопределять можно, правда, не везде работает.

Comment: Покусанные углы - классика border-radius :) Тут уже как браузер отрендерит

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0.5px solid var(--black, #1d1c23);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row:first-child .bem-table__cell:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row:first-child .bem-table__cell:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row:last-child .bem-table__cell:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row:last-child .bem-table__cell:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row__cell {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid var(--black, #1d1c23);
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row:not(:last-child) .blog .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__row__cell:last-child {
  border-right: 0.5px solid var(--black, #1d1c23);
}
 .wp-block-lazyblock-tablica .bem-table__cell {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 24px;
  color: var(--black, #1d1c23);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150%; /* 33px */
  border: 0.5px solid var(--black, #1d1c23);
}
```

```html
<div class="lazyblock wp-block-lazyblock-tablica">
                    <h2 class="single__title">Таблица</h2>
                    <table class="bem-table">
                      <tbody class="bem-table__body">
                        <tr class="bem-table__row">
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст левой колонки текст левой колонки</td>
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст правой колонки текст правой колонки</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bem-table__row">
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст левой колонки текст левой колонки</td>
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст правой колонки текст правой колонки</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bem-table__row">
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст левой колонки текст левой колонки</td>
                          <td class="bem-table__cell">Текст правой колонки текст правой колонки</td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Repeat the row as needed for your content -->
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Не знаю почему, браузеры неправильно воспринимают в такой ситуации `border-radius`, но должен быть в ячейках чуть меньше. Подбирите сами, он точно везде будет одинаковый.